# Angular - Raising the same event for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with ng-repeat directive. I am cloning the whole form on some event, each form has the same function (assigned to the ) -  `openStart($event)` and if I am triggering event on the first form, the second triggers automatically. 
How to make separate event/function for each form (ng-repeat object)?

```
<form name="universityForm" novalidate ng-repeat="university in education.universities track by university['id']">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="school">School</label>
                <input type="text"
                       ng-model="university.name"
                       class="form-control"
                       id="school"
                       placeholder="Enter school name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="faculty">Faculty</label>
                <input type="text"
                       ng-model="university.faculty"
                       class="form-control"
                       id="faculty"
                       placeholder="Faculty">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="degree">Degree</label>
                <input type="text"
                       ng-model="university.degree"
                       class="form-control"
                       id="degree"
                       placeholder="Degree" required>
            </div>

                        .... some markup here ....

              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button"
                        class="btn btn-default"
                        ng-click="openStart($event)"><i class="glyphicon      glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </button>
              </span>

            </form>
```

My openStar function (I'm using Angular ui data picker):

```
$scope.openEnd = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.openedStart = false;
        $scope.openedEnd = true;
    };
```

Comment: Can you post the openStart function? Or the whole controller?

Comment: Of course, I have add the function to my question

Comment: I don't understand what differentiates a click from each cloned form. If this is your `openStart` function, it will do the same thing no matter the form it's clicked from. What's supposed to be different?

Comment: Yeah, It does the same thing, but the problem is that it opens 2, 3..N layers, depends on numbers of forms. But, should open just for one, that was clicked

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try looking at the $event.currentTarget to see which element triggered the event.  Do something like this:

```
//formsToToggle would be the IDs of the forms in the html.
var formsToToggle = ['universityForm_1', 'universityForm_2', 'universityForm_3'];

$scope.toggleForms = function(form){
     for(var i = 0, len = formsToToggle.length; i < len; i++){
         if(form === formsToToggle[i])
             $scope[form] = true;
         else
             $scope[formsToToggle[i]] = false;
     }
};

//Grabs the event object's id and passes that into the formsToToggle function
  $scope.openEnd = function($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();

var target = ($event.currentTarget) ? $event.currentTarget: $event.srcElement;
      $scope.toggleForms(target.id);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping hand, but fix was easy, just to change `$scope` to `this`

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix - `this`
The function will be:

```
$scope.openEnd = function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.openedStart = false;
    this.openedEnd = true;
};
```

and it will work for appropriate object

Comment: You might find you'll be able to use `$scope` instead of `this` if you set the `$scope.openedStart` and `$scope.openedEnd` within the immediate controller `function`